# Deploy same clickonce application on different servers/installurls

Tags: .net, clickonce

I'm in the process of having to install/publish the same ClickOnce application on several different servers - I can't have a central site.

Do I have to publish the same app several times with only the InstallUrl changed, or is there another way ? A programatically solution ?

Comment: Is each server also going to act
as the update location?

Comment: @thedugas Yes, each server will be its own update location, and independent of eachother.

Comment: Are users tied to a single server or is it possible for a single user to install the same app from multiple servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by using a build script (MsBuild in our case) with parameters depending on the  deployment instance. The builds tasks are available out of the box.
I find this simpler than a programatic solution.

Comment: Can anyone kindly let me know how to use MSBuild for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Check out mage.exe - MageUI is a graphical front-end.

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding your requirement. What I was suggesting was using mage.exe from a script to create a deployment for each server or making copies of the orginal publication then using mage.exe to edit the ProviderUrl of the Manifest 
See:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/1d5c722b-5a15-4783-88b5-0da93a3577c3/"
And
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174764/how-to-move-a-clickonce-deployment-package"
And
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx